# Condiontionalpannel Multiple Conditions and Calculating Age (R Shiny Dashboard)

Tags: r, date, shiny

I was wondering if I could get your help.

**Background:** I am building a shiny app (see here: https://camh-nds.shinyapps.io/STOPDataQuality/) to help with data quality control

**PROBLEM #1**

In the "SOR" tab, Step 1: the goal is to notify the user if `DateSurveyed` = `WorkshopDate` and display the appropriate message if it correct or not. This works fine.

For Step 2: a valid `QuitDate` falls between this range:
`DateSurveyed`>= `QuitDate` <= `DateSurveyed` + days(30)

If this condition is satisfied display the following text: "The Quit Date entered is valid.

If the condition is not satisfied I would like to display the corrected quit dates.

- The correct quit dates is based on:

i) if `QuitDate` < `DateSurveyed`, then display the following text: "Correct Quit Date is [value of `DateSurveyed` here]

ii) if `QuitDate` > `DateSurveyed` + days (30) then display the following text: "Correct Quit Date is [value of `DateSurveyed + days(30)` here].

Here is the ui code

```
dashboardBody(
            tabItems(  
              #Data Quality for Stop on The Road (SOR)
              tabItem(tabName="SOR",
              #Checking if Date Surveyed= Workshop Date         
                      h3("Step 1- check to see if Date Surveyed = Workshop Date"),
                      HTML ('</br>'),
              #Entering Date Surveyed  
                      dateInput('date',
                        label='Date Surveyed: yyyy-mm-dd'),
              #Entering Workshop Date    
                   dateInput('date2',
                       label='Workshop Date: yyyy-mm-dd'),
              #If DateSurveyed=WorkShopDate display this message
              conditionalPanel("input.date==input.date2",
                               textOutput("EqualDates")),
              #If DateSurveyed!=WorkshopDate display this message
              conditionalPanel ("input.date!=input.date2",
                               textOutput("ErrorDates")),
              HTML ('</br>'),
              HTML ('</br>'),
              HTML ('</br>'),
              #Checking to see if a Valid Quit Date has been entered
              h3("Step 2- check to see if subject has entered a valid quit date"),
              #Description to user what is a Valid Quit date 
              h5("* Note: Quit Dates can start as early as Date Surveyed or be set on 30 days after the Date Surveyed"),
              HTML ('</br>'),
              #Entering Quit Dates
              dateInput('date3',
                        label='Quit Date: yyyy-mm-dd'),

              #Valid Quit Dates: if QuitDate>=DateSurveyed AND QuitDate<=DateSurveyed + days(30); 
              #Then display message
              conditionalPanel("input.date3>=input.date && input.date3<=input.date + days(30)",
              #HELP! Conditional statement is not working!!!                 
                               textOutput("ValidQuitDate")),

              #Incorrect Quit Dates: if QuitDate<DateSurveyed OR QuitDate>DateSurveyed + days(30); 
              #Then display message 
              conditionalPanel("input.date3<input.date || input.date3>input.date + days(30)",
              #HELP! Conditional statement is not working!!!                 
                               textOutput("InvalidQuitDate"))
              ),
```

server:

```
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

#SOR Date Surveyed   
output$dateText  <- renderText({
paste("input$date is", as.character(input$date))
})

#SOR Work Shop Date  
output$dateText2 <- renderText({
paste("input$date2 is", as.character(input$date2))
})

#SOR: if DateSurveyed=WorkshopDate then display this message  
 output$EqualDates<- renderText({
 "**CORRECT** Dates are Equal!!!"
 })
#SOR: if DateSurveyed!= WorkshopDate then display this message   
 output$ErrorDates<- renderText({
 "**ERROR** Dates are NOT Equal"
})
#SOR: if QuitDate=DateSurveyed OR QuitDate<= DateSurveyed+ days(30) then 
display this message 
output$ValidQuitDate<- renderText({
 "You have entered a Valid Quit Date"
}) 

#SOR: if QuitDate<DateSurveyed OR QuitDate>DateSurveyed+ days(30) then 
display this message
output$InvalidQuitDate<- renderText({
 "**ERROR** Incorrect Quit Date Entered"
}) 




})
```

**Problem 2: Calculating Age**

In the Age Tab, I simply want to calculate the age using the following formula:
Age=(Date Sureyed-DateOfBirth)/365. I would like to display the answer as for example: 19 years old and 3 months if possible.

Here is the link the my Github repo: https://github.com/AhmadMobin/STOPDQ

Appreciate the help I can get!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since date manipulation doesn't seam as easy in javascript as in shiny - I would solve this with `conditionalPanel` but rather solve it in the `renderText` it selves like this

```
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  #SOR Date Surveyed   
  output$dateText  <- renderText({
    paste("input$date is", as.character(input$date))
  })

  #SOR Work Shop Date  
  output$dateText2 <- renderText({
    paste("input$date2 is", as.character(input$date2))
  })

  #SOR: if DateSurveyed=WorkshopDate then display this message  
  output$TestDates<- renderText({
    if(input$date == input$date2){
      "**CORRECT** Dates are Equal!!!"
    } else {
      "**ERROR** Dates are NOT Equal"
    }
  })
  #SOR: if DateSurveyed!= WorkshopDate then display this message   
  output$ErrorDates<- renderText({
  })
  #SOR: if QuitDate=DateSurveyed OR QuitDate<= DateSurveyed+ days(30) then 
  # display this message 
  output$ValidQuitDate<- renderText({
    if(input$date3 >= input$date && input$date3 <= input$date + 30){
      "You have entered a Valid Quit Date"
    } else if(input$date3 < input$date){
      paste("**ERROR** Incorrect Quit Date Entered
      Correct Quit Date is",input$date)
    } else {
      paste("**ERROR** Incorrect Quit Date Entered
      Correct Quit Date is",input$date + days(30))
    }
  }) 

  #SOR: if QuitDate<DateSurveyed OR QuitDate>DateSurveyed+ days(30) then 
  # display this message
  output$InvalidQuitDate<- renderText({
  }) 




}
ui <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(  
    #Data Quality for Stop on The Road (SOR)
    tabItem(tabName="SOR",
            #Checking if Date Surveyed= Workshop Date         
            h3("Step 1- check to see if Date Surveyed = Workshop Date"),
            HTML ('</br>'),
            #Entering Date Surveyed  
            dateInput('date',
                      label='Date Surveyed: yyyy-mm-dd'),
            #Entering Workshop Date    
            dateInput('date2',
                      label='Workshop Date: yyyy-mm-dd'),
            #If DateSurveyed=WorkShopDate display this message
            textOutput("TestDates"),
            HTML ('</br>'),
            HTML ('</br>'),
            HTML ('</br>'),
            #Checking to see if a Valid Quit Date has been entered
            h3("Step 2- check to see if subject has entered a valid quit date"),
            #Description to user what is a Valid Quit date 
            h5("* Note: Quit Dates can start as early as Date Surveyed or be set on 30 days after the Date Surveyed"),
            HTML ('</br>'),
            #Entering Quit Dates
            dateInput('date3',
                      label='Quit Date: yyyy-mm-dd'),

            #Valid Quit Dates: if QuitDate>=DateSurveyed AND QuitDate<=DateSurveyed + days(30); 
            #Then display message
            textOutput("ValidQuitDate")
    )
  )
)
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

hope this helps!

Comment: @AhmadMobin Sorry forgot that have updated my code with a solution for that as well. Please check if it is what you ment

Comment: Hi @Bertil Nestorius, This puts me in the right direction. I would also like to provide the right QuitDates based on the following conditions: i) if QuitDate < DateSurveyed (Quit Date before Date Surveyed), then display the following text: "Correct Quit Date is [value of DateSurveyed here] ii) if QuitDate > DateSurveyed + days (30) (Quit Date 31 days after Date Surveyed) then display the following text: "Correct Quit Date is [value of DateSurveyed + days(30) here].

Comment: Hi @Bertil Nestorius your update code is not showing the correct quit dates based on this logic:
i) if the Quit Date is before Date Surveyed then the Corrected Quit Date is the Date Surveyed
ii) else if the Quit Date is after Date Surveyed plus 30 days then the corrected Quit Date is DateSurvey+30days

hope that makes sense. Thanks so much for your help though, making progress!

Comment: sorry obviusly a bit sleepy - is it ok now?

Comment: Thanks so much @Bertil Nestorius. Your code worked!

I cleaned it up but here is what the final code can be found here: https://github.com/AhmadMobin/STOPDQ

You have helped me a lot already, i feel bad to keep bugging you but any chance you can help me solve Problem # 2?

Problem 2: Calculating Age

In the Age Tab, I simply want to calculate the age using the following formula: Age=(Date Sureyed-DateOfBirth)/365. I would like to display the answer as for example: 19 years old and 3 months and 12 days if possible. Shiny app is here: https://camh-nds.shinyapps.io/STOPDataQuality/